# C counting word program works if there is no space between symbols, why?

Tags: c, regex, count, scanf, words

This is the code I'm using and it works perfectly unless:

1. The text file starts with integers.
2. If there is no space between symbols e.g [hi!] works perfectly  but [hi !] prints �
3. If i put multiple symbols together e.g [?????????] the number of words will be incorrect.

Just to clarify it is fine if there are integers within the code but not if they are at the start.

Why is that the case? I am really curious how to solve that issue.

EDIT:
It was pointed out to me that fscanf does not support regex, why does it filter out the letters correctly then?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* counts words in the file */
int main(void) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    int r,n,i; /* a variable for result of a function, returning int */
     /* the words counter */
    const char *filename = "test2.txt"; /* a file name opening for read */
    char word[10]; /* an array for the check if a non-empty word was read */

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: file" "\n");
        return 1;
    }  
    /* if can't open the file for read
       then print an error message and return false to the environment */
    int arraylen = sizeof(word)/sizeof(word[0]); /*write the length of array word to arraylen*/ 
    n = 0; /* turn the counter of words to zero */
    word[0] = '\0'; /* turn the word array to an empty state */
   while ((r = fscanf(fp, "\n%10[^A-Za-z]%*c", word)) == 1) {
        printf("firstoutput\n");
        for(i=0;i<arraylen;i++)

                printf("%c",word[i]);


    if((r = fscanf(fp, "\n%[A-Za-z]%*c", word)) == 0) { /*in case next character is not a 
        letter do nothing, this is in place to prevent the program from getting stuck*/

         printf("secondoutput\n");
        for(i=0;i<arraylen;i++)
            if(word[i] != (' '))
                printf("%c",word[i]);
        }

        if (word[0] != '\0')
            n++;
        /* if the word array got something,
           then it was a word, count it */ 

        word[0] = '\0'; /* turn the word back into an empty state */
    }  
    /* skipping words delimeted by ' ' or '\n' or ','
       while file fp can be read, continue skipping
       and count every skip */


    if (ferror(fp) != 0) { /* check the file for read error if EOF occured */
        fprintf(stderr, "error: read file" "\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
    /* if there was an error while reading the file
       then print error, close the file (because it was opened though)
       and return false to the environment */

    if (n == 1) /* control "to be" and endings for word or words */
        printf("\nthere is %d word" "\n", n);
    else
        printf("\nthere are %d words" "\n", n);

    fclose(fp); /* close the file */

    return 0; /* return success to the environment */
}
```

EDIT2 : Im posting a full solution which works 101%, I combined all the various tips and stuff I found and created this, I believe this solution is extremely compact and efficient, if I am in the wrong do correct me !

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORD "A-Za-z"


int countWords(FILE *f,int* now){
   char ch[100][100];
   int x;
   *now=0;
   int count = 0;
       while (fscanf(f, "%[^" WORD "]",ch[count]) != EOF
        && fscanf(f, "%10[" WORD "]",ch[count]) != EOF) {

        if(count>0) {

        for(x=0;x<count;x++) {

          if((strcasecmp(ch[count],ch[x]))==0) { /* Compare if the two words match, 
          case insensitive*/
            if(fscanf(f, "%[^" WORD "]",ch[count]) != EOF
            && fscanf(f, "%10[" WORD "]",ch[count]) != EOF) /* Since the words match,
            now we have to overwrite the double word by scanning the next set of characters.*/
              printf("String is equal\n");

              (*now)++;
          }
        }
      }
        puts(ch[count]);
        count++;
        (*now)++;
    }
    puts(ch[13]);
    printf("%d\n",*now );

   return count;
}

int main(void){

   int uniquewordCount=0,wordCount=0;
   FILE *rFile = fopen("test2.txt", "r");
   uniquewordCount += countWords(rFile,&wordCount);
   printf("%d\n",(a+b));
   printf("Amount of unique words: %d\n", uniquewordCount);
   printf("Amount of words: %d\n", wordCount);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf` does not support regex.

Comment: Well, it supports the character range format `%[`, which looks a bit like a regex character range. Still, it's no regex, of course.

Comment: Care to elaborate why it is working (somewhat) correctly then ?

Comment: After the definition `char word[10];` you cannot use `10` in the `scanf()` format conversion: you must take into account the `'\0'` terminator: `fscanf(fp, " %9[^A-Za-z]%*c", ...)`

Comment: @pmg I am aware of that, I was just surprised it still worked with the 10 in place, I put that in place because when scanning the array through the loop it seemed that the first letter of each word was being "eaten", I thought it would fix that issue which it did not.

Comment: Of course the first letter gets eaten; you told the program to do so by reading an extra char with `%*c`. If you only want to count the number of words, the `fscanf` approach seems too complicated.

Comment: If you are not going to do anyting with `r` except compare it to 0 or 1 right away, you could just as easily do without it and save some parens in the if/while constructs.

Comment: Rather than attempt to repair this approach, suggest reading the line with `fgets()` and then parsing with `sscanf()`

Comment: @chux I will try this approach and post back results, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first scanning command is

```
fscanf(fp, "\n%10[^A-Za-z]%*c", word)
```

This will skip any white-space (`"\n"`), then read into a buffer of up to 10 chars that are not letters (`"%10[^A-Za-z]"`) and finally read the character after that (`"*c"`).

You don't enter the `while` loop when the file begins with a letter, because `fscanf` will return 0, as it cound't scan a non-empty string of non-letters. If you even skip white space before that, the while loop is only entered when the first non-space character is not a letter, which is not very likely.

Because you read an extra character at the end of the `fscanf`, your words will miss their first letter.

By constraining the word to 10 letters, you read longer words in chunks, which should throw your word count off by counting longer words a stwo or three words. The char buffer `word` should also have at least 11 chars.

The proper way to print a string is to `printf("%s", word)`or to `puts(word)` it. Your loop is basically okay, but prints all ten letters even if the word might have fewer letters.

I don't think that using `fscanf` is a good way to count words, but if you want to use it, you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORD "A-Za-z0-9'"

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = stdin;
    int n = 0;

    while (fscanf(fp, "%*[^" WORD "]") != EOF
        && fscanf(fp, "%*[" WORD "]") != EOF) {
        n++;
    }

    printf("%d words\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, we `fscanf` for non-words and words alternately and end the lopp when one of the `fscanf`s signals the end of the file. Note that we don't care about the actual contents, as we skip them by not converting anything with the `*` asterisk. That means that the only outcome of the `fscanf` can be 0 and `EOF`.

The usual approach to count words is to read chars and detect when the "context" switches from non-words to words:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isword(int c)
{
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') return 1;
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') return 1;
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') return 1;
    if (c == '-') return 1;
    if (c == '\'') return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = stdin;       // or use a real file, of course
    int word = 0;           // 0: space cntext, 1: word context
    int n = 0;

    for (;;) {
        int c = fgetc(fp);

        if (c == EOF) break;

        if (isword(c)) {
            if (word == 0) n++;
            word = 1;
        } else {
            word = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("%d words\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

What counts as a word is defined here by the function `isword`. Note how there is no need to keep two `fscanf` formats in sync. A letter is part of a word or it is not., That's unambiguous with the `else` clause.

Comment: This clarifies a lot of the concepts I have wrongly assumed in my head, thank you very much for this.

Comment: Elegant use of `[^...]` and `[...]`.  Minor:  `'` in `"A-Za-z0-9'"`?? .  `WORD` inconsistent with `isword(int c)` .  `WORD` not used in 2nd snippet.

Comment: @chux: I've included the apostrophe so that the English contractions (_you're_, _it's_) and possessives will be one word. The `WORD` in the second snipped is a leftover from its incarnation as first snippet; I'll remove it. Thanks.